# WebView and rounded Corner for Mac App

Tags: xcode

How do i add rounded Corners to a Mac App Webview?

I googled around and i found some how toe but they are all for UIWebView,

tried to port this down to Mac App, but this doesn't work while some properties were unknown says xCpde like

```
setClipsToBounds
```

I also maybe do it wrong , i have a Winodw and a View Subclass:

myWindow.h/,m
myView.h/.m

and my AppDelegate.h/.m

In which File do i need to add this settings so the WebView is known and the properties are available?

thx for help

Comment: why do you need a window subclass for this? (or is that not related?) are you trying to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684861/nswindow-place-part-of-image-outside-window/19688310#19688310

Comment: No, it results from an Example how to create a Rounded Corners Window with Shadows etc...

Comment: But anyway, do you have an idea how to solve this issue with corners on web view?

Answer (score -1):

After googling for a solution and various tries, it seems this isn't supported for Mac OSX, there are answers on the web but they all refer to UIWebView, the WebView for Desktops seems not to support this...

Comment: this is not true; im sure of it. maybe you should post the links of how to do this with `UIKit` and somebody can adapt it for you.